# SQLite command from bash

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite

I need to record temperatures to a SQLite-DB on a linux system (using bash)

My problem is that I get the temperature readings in an individual file.
How can I get that reading into the SQLite command

```
 sqlite3 mydb "INSERT INTO readings (TStamp, reading) VALUES (datetime(), 'xxx');"
```

The file contains just one line with the value "45.7" and should replace the xxx.
Using fix data the SQL command works pretty well.

Comment: Please add sample input file to your question.

Comment: You might be interested in the `.import` CLI command: https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `echo` commands to the `sqlite3`, just like this:

```
temp=`cat file_with_temperature_value`
echo "INSERT INTO readings (TStamp, reading) VALUES (datetime(), '$temp');" | sqlite3 mydb
```

or do it like in your example:

```
temp=`cat file_with_temperature_value`
sqlite3 mydb "INSERT INTO readings (TStamp, reading) VALUES (datetime(), '$temp');"
```